# Definition of product of two random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, definition, covariance

Suppose you have two random variables

$X:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ and $Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$

which are not necessarily independent.

How is the product $XY$ defined and how do I calculate the image of the new random variable $Z:=XY$?

In the context of covariance of finite random variables we are told to simply multiply all elements of each image, $X(\Omega)$ and $Y(\Omega)$, with each other. However, we are not provided with any formal definition. So I have no idea what to do when we have non-finite random variables.

Which makes it even more confusing is that the professor uses the following notation when he states a Lemma about the expected value of $XY$ when both random variables are independent:

> *Lemma:*
>
> The expected value, $\mathbb{E}(XY)$ exists iff $\sum\limits_{\omega\in \Omega}|X(\omega)Y(\omega)|p(\omega)<\infty$.
>
> *Proof*
>
> $\sum\limits_{\omega\in \Omega}|X(\omega)Y(\omega)|p(\omega)=\sum\limits_{x\in X(\Omega)}\sum\limits_{y\in Y(\Omega)}|xy|\sum\limits_{\omega: X(\omega)=x, Y(\omega)=y}p(\omega)= $ ...

So here it seems that the expression $XY$ is treated like the multiplication of two real-valued functions.

Can someone give me an explanation of $XY$?

Comment: Just pointwise multiplication.  So $(XY)(\omega) = X(\omega) * Y(\omega)$.

Comment: $X$ and $Y$ are functions. So $XY$ is the function $X(t)Y(t)$

Comment: Whoever told you to "multiply all elements of each image, $X(\Omega)$ and $Y(\Omega)$ with each other" was wrong.  @btilly has given the correct definition. (And now so has David Peterson.)

Comment: @DavidPetersen But this would be inconsistent with calculating the covariance of two finite random variables because in this case we have the following: Let be $X(\Omega)=\{x_1, x_2\}$ and $Y(\Omega)=\{y_1, y_2\}$. Then we are told to calculate $cov(XY)$ as follows: $cov(XY)=x_1y_1 P(x_1,y_1) + x_1y_2P(x_1,y_2) +x_2y_1P(x_2,y_1) +x_2y_2P(x_2,y_2) - \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y)$.

Comment: Saying "$X(\Omega) = \{x_1, x_2\}$" doesn't describe a function $X : \Omega \to \mathbb R$, though! For each $\omega \in \Omega$, you should say what $X(\omega)$ is.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, thanks for the remark: But this would be inconsistent with calculating the covariance of two finite random variables because in this case we have the following: Let be $X(\Omega)=\{X(\omega_1)=x_1,X(\omega_2)=x_2\}$ and $Y(Ω)=\{Y(\omega_1)=y_1,Y(\omega_2)=y_2\}$. Then we are told to calculate $cov(XY)$ as follows: $cov(XY)=x_1y_1P(x_1,y_1)+x_1y_2P(x_1,y_2)+x_2y_1P(x_2,y_1)+x_2y_2P(x_2,y_2)−\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$.

Comment: If you set up the functions as in the last comment then $P(x_1,y_2)=P(x_2,y_1)=0$ and the covariance is easy to compute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to address an apparent point of confusion in the comments:
"$X(\Omega)=\{X(\omega_1)=x_1,X(\omega_2)=x_2\}$
and $Y(Ω)=\{Y(\omega_1)=y_1,Y(\omega_2)=y_2\}$."

That is *not* how random variables work in general.
In general, the preimage of $x_1$ under $X$ is some subset of $\Omega,$ not just a single value $\omega_1,$ and likewise for the preimage of $y_1$ under $Y.$
It is possible for these two preimages to overlap but to be different from each other.

For example, we might have $\Omega = \{\omega_1, \omega_2, \omega_3, \omega_4\}$
and furthermore
\begin{align}
X(\omega_1) &= X(\omega_2) = x_1, \\
X(\omega_3) &= X(\omega_4) = x_2, \\
Y(\omega_1) &= Y(\omega_3) = y_1, \\
Y(\omega_2) &= Y(\omega_4) = y_2.
\end{align}

In this way $p(\omega_1) = \mathbb P(X=x_1,Y=y_1),$
$p(\omega_2) = \mathbb P(X=x_1,Y=y_2),$ 
$p(\omega_3) = \mathbb P(X=x_2,Y=y_1),$ and 
$p(\omega_4) = \mathbb P(X=x_2,Y=y_2).$
Similarly,
$X(\omega_1)Y(\omega_1)p(\omega_1) = x_1 y_1 \mathbb P(X=x_1,Y=y_1)$ and so forth.

So now if $P(\omega_1) = P(\omega_2) = P(\omega_3) = P(\omega_4) = \frac14,$
then $X$ and $Y$ would be independent variables.
But if $P(\omega_1) = P(\omega_4) = \frac12$ and
$P(\omega_2) = P(\omega_3) = 0$ with $x_1\neq x_2$ and $y_1\neq y_2$ then $X$ and $Y$ can be expressed as functions of each other.

Consider the case where $P(\omega_1) = P(\omega_4) = \frac13$ and
$P(\omega_2) = P(\omega_3) = \frac16,$ 
and suppose $x_1= y_1=1$ and $x_2= y_2=2.$
Then
\begin{align}
x_1y_1P(x_1,y_1) &= 1\cdot 1\cdot\frac13 = \frac13,\\
x_1y_2P(x_1,y_2) &= 1\cdot 2\cdot\frac16 = \frac13,\\
x_2y_1P(x_2,y_1) &= 2\cdot 1\cdot\frac16 = \frac13,\\
x_2y_2P(x_2,y_2) &= 2\cdot 2\cdot\frac13 = \frac43,\\
\mathbb{E}(X) &= \mathbb{E}(Y) = \frac32,
\end{align}
and therefore
\begin{align}
\mathrm{cov}(XY) &= 
\left(\sum_{\omega\in\Omega} X(\omega)Y(\omega)P(\omega)\right)
−\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y) \\
&= x_1y_1P(x_1,y_1)+x_1y_2P(x_1,y_2)+x_2y_1P(x_2,y_1)+x_2y_2P(x_2,y_2)
−\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y) \\
&=\frac73 - \frac94 = \frac1{12}.
\end{align}

All the definitions and formulas work perfectly well.
There is no inconsistency among them.

---

In general, if $Z = XY$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables, then
$Z(\omega) = X(\omega) Y(\omega)$ for any $\omega \in \Omega.$
In other words, it *is* the product of two functions on the probability space.
This is true whether the probability space has a finite or infinite number of elements.

The summation notation $\sum_{\omega\in\Omega}$ is good for finite probability space or for a countably infinite probability space.
For continuous distributions one generally uses some form of integration rather than summation. But in any case the interpretation of $Z=XY$
as $Z(\omega)=X(\omega)Y(\omega)$  is true for every $\omega$ in the probability space no matter how many elements the space has.

Comment: Yes I know that random variables are not a bijective mapping in general. It was just a quick example to keep things simple.

Comment: Sometimes it is possible to make things _too_ simple. But you keep saying there is an inconsistency. I just worked out a complete example and see no difficulty anywhere. What is the concern?

Comment: As far as I understood your example it only shows how to calculate the covariance if you already assume how to evaluate the expression $XY$. However, my original question was how the expression $XY$ is evaluated in general and this is not adressed in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment, I think your confusion stems from some misleading notation from your source material. (Without further context it is hard to clarify.)

If $X(\omega_1) = x_1$ and $X(\omega_2) = x_2$ and $Y(\omega_1) = y_1$ and $Y(\omega_2) = y_2$, then indeed we would have $E[XY] = x_1 y_1 P(x_1, y_1) + x_2 y_2 P(x_2, y_2)$ (without the other two terms).

If instead you are in some sort of product space $\Omega \times \Omega' = \{\omega_1, \omega_2\} \times \{\omega'_1, \omega'_2\}$ where $(X,Y)(\omega, \omega') = (X(\omega), Y(\omega'))$,
and we have $X(\omega_1) = x_1$ and $X(\omega_2) = x_2$ and $Y(\omega_1') = y_1$ and $Y(\omega_2') = y_2$,
then when computing the expectation $E[XY]$ you need to sum over all four elements of $\Omega \times \Omega'$, which yields $E[XY] = x_1 y_1 P(x_1, y_1) + x_1 y_2 P(x_1, y_2) + x_2 y_1 P(x_2, y_1) + x_2 y_2 P(x_2, y_2)$. I think the confusion arose because your material opted to have $\Omega = \Omega'$ and overloaded the notation for the two different components of the sample space.

Comment: I would have assumed that in the original notation, $X$ is not a one-to-one function on $\Omega,$ and likewise for $Y,$ so it might be that $X(\omega_1) = X(\omega_2) = x_1$ while $X(\omega_3) = X(\omega_4) = x_2,$ $Y(\omega_1) = X(\omega_3) = y_1$, and  $Y(\omega_2) = X(\omega_4) = y_2.$ So there are four possible values of $(X,Y)$ even though each of the individual variables has only two possible values. In other words, where $\Omega$ appears in the original material they meant what you meant by $\Omega\times\Omega'$.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, that is what Misha Lavrov is trying to explain. I am not sure if OP's use of $X(\Omega) = \{X(\omega_1) = x_1, X(\omega_2) = x_2\}$ is his own misunderstanding or if it was given to him in his reading material. I may delete my answer if I've misinterpreted the source of OP's confusion.

Comment: OK, I see we understand it the same way. I'm expanding on Misha's comment in an answer now, let's see how it goes.

Comment: Our professor neither stated that $XY$ is a function $XY:\Omega_1\times\Omega_2\to\mathbb{R}$ with $(XY)(\omega_1,\omega_2):=X(\omega_1)⋅Y(\omega_2)$ nor did he explicitly say that $XY$ is a function $XY:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ with $(XY)(\omega)=X(\omega)Y(\omega)$.He simply came up with this Lemma in which he evaluates $XY$ as I described in my question. If our professor had stated somehting like angryavian said,then it would be clear to me how to deal with $XY$, but he didn't do it at any point in our material.That's why I was wondering if there is a general definition of how to evaluate $XY$.